# jq if condition matches, needs to print pod name

Tags: jq

Command:

```
kubectl get pods web-www-7f8b64fc8d-bkmbk web-www2-6f78b88864-9jmxn -o json |jq '.items[].spec.volumes[].configMap|select(.name=="webdata")|.name'
```

output:

```
"webdata"
"webdata"
```

but instead of ".name"
want to print ".items[].metadata.name"

Comment: kubectl get pods web-www-7f8kubectl get pods skunk-agentlogin-7f8b64fc8d-bkmbk skunk-backoffice-6f78b88864-9jmxn -o json |jq '.items[].spec.volumes[].configMap|select(.name=="skunk-conf")|.items[].metadata.name' 
jq: error (at <stdin>:1370): Cannot iterate over null (null). web-www2-b64fc8d-bkmbk -6f78b88864-9jmxn -o json |jq '.items[].spec.volumes[].configMap|select(.name=="webdata")|.items[].metadata.name' 
jq: error (at <stdin>:1370): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: ".items[].metadata.name" gives error as jq: error (at <stdin>:1370): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: See [ask], without a [mre], how are we supposed to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
.items[] as $i
| spec.volumes[].configMap|select(.name=="webdata")
| $i
| .metadata.name
```